# Point network solutions domain to fatcow

Tags: domain

I bought a domain on network solutions and I bought hosting on fatcow.com.  How can I point my domain on NS to fatcow?  I don't want to transfer my domain name to fatcow because i like NS and it costs more money.  I've tried editing the DNS in network solutions by entering the 2 nameservers

example:

```
ns1.fatcow.com
ns2.fatcow.com
```

but this doesn't seem to work.  fatcow only gives me those 2 nameservers and a website IP.  im not sure how NS knows to go to specific domain (like example.com) with only that information.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you set your DNS on your domain! Just wait if your site doesn't load because maybe your ISP Cache didn't update yet!

Comment: @SepahradSalour how do i set my DNS on my domain?  isn't that what i did?  and iv'e waiting way longer than the 48 hours.

Comment: In your domain handle there is an option like DNS Management, Write your DNS on it one by one.

Comment: @SepahradSalour im not sure what you're referring to.  please check out my updated answer with the screenshot

Comment: Yes it's done! If your web site doesn't load after 48Hours contact to your WebHosting. Before that ask your friend to test your domain if he/she couldn't to load your website contact to your webhosting.